# Mapping Revisions Table in Fluent NHibernate

Tags: inheritance, fluent-nhibernate, triggers, nhibernate-mapping, revisions

I want to audit my `Posts` table by preserving whole record changes to a `PostRevisions` table before `Post` rows are updated. `PostRevision` entities should store all the `Post` entity columns along with a `RevisionId` column.

I want to map this with Fluent NHibernate. `PostRevision` entities should mirror the properties of `Post` entities, but without having to maintain two entity classes and mapping classes.

How should I design my entities and mappings to do achieve this?

### Desired pseudocode for Post Edit

```
var post = _unitOfWork.CurrentSession.Get<Post>(id);
var postRevision = new PostRevision(post);

post.Content = "changed value"; // change some things here

_unitOfWork.CurrentSession.Save(post);
_unitOfWork.CurrentSession.Save(postRevision);

_unitOfWork.Commit();
```

### `PostRevision` composition class:

```
public class PostRevision
{
    public virtual Guid Id { get; private set; }
    public virtual Post Post { get; set; }

    public PostRevision()
    {
    }

    public PostRevision(Post post)
    {
        this.Post = post;
    }
}
```

### Possible Fluent Mapping:

```
public class PostRevisionMap : ClassMap<PostRevision>
{
    public PostRevisionMap()
    {
        Id(x => x.Id);
        Component(x => x.Post); // will something like this work?
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

the relation (I think) you're looking for is one-to-many: a Post has many PostRevisions.
a PostRevision references a single Post.
Therefore I think the correct mapping on the Post side would be

```
HasMany(x=> x.PostRevisions);
```

and on the PostRevision side:

```
References(x=> x.Post).
```

see the [nHibernate docs](http://nhforge.org/doc/nh/en/index.html#collections) for a more complete look on how to map these associations.

**Edit**
If you want to keep a history record for each revision of your post, you have 2 options:
1. add a boolean 'IsHistoric' field to your Post class. Whenever a Post is revised, you don't change the Post object itself, but rather mark it as 'IsHistoric = true' and create a new Post object which represents the revised Post. This is the method I use in my project.
2. Create a 'HistoricPost' class which inherits from Post. You don't have to repeat your mapping, and you can use a seperate table for this class (table-per-subclass strategy).
see [here](http://wiki.fluentnhibernate.org/Fluent_mapping#Subclasses) for further details.
I *think* you can also specify a different Id column for the child class, using `Id(x => x.SomeOtherId);` in the mapping of 'HistoricPost'. I haven't tried it though, so I'm not 100% sure.

Comment: @sJhonny, what should the class mapping for `PostRevisions` look like if I don't want to duplicate all the mapping properties?

Comment: The mapping would have exactly 2 lines- one to map the id (something like Id(x=> x.Id) ), and the other- the one i've posted. That's it.
since the Post entity is already mapped on its own, you don't need to map it again.

Comment: @sJhonny, I'll make my question clearer. `Post` in `PostRevision` should be a value-object, not an entity reference. Before updating a Post record, its present value is preserved to the `PostRevisions` table.

Comment: sorry, I didn't realize that. in that case, I see 2 options- either create a new entity (PostHistory) which inherits from Post, and reference it in the PostRevision class (see this question- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2041567/nhibernate-map-one-class-to-two-identical-tables). Another option is to add a boolean field to the Post class- IsHistoric (or some such). On every revision, you would actually create a new Post instance, and update the IsHistoric field of the existing one.

Comment: @sJhonny, for option 1, how can `PostHistory` inherit the mappings for `Post` without code-duplication?

Comment: Ah! I didn't know it could handle separate tables per subclass. Put that as your answer and I'll mark it as accepted.

Comment: @sJohnny, Can I unmap the parent class ID so the sub-class can have it's own ID?